# What is the simplest way to copy project folder to new Mac with updated IOS and Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

I recently acquired a newer MacBook to run the most recent iOS and Xcode versions. I copied a project folder to the new Mac and opened it with Xcode 11.4 (was 10.1 on old Mac).  I get 14 errors all related to "Failed to render and update auto layout status for ..VeiwController".  The simulator runs fine, but the main storyboard doesn't render the button icons properly.  I can add new constraints to the buttons to show them properly but the errors don't go away. I assume I have lost some info/files related to autolayout when I copied folders.  I have read about similar issues. Most talk about using Github or some other 3rd party for maintaining files. Is there any other way to get this done?  It seems like updates computers/software should be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Since reporting this, I have used the same process of copying folders of all other projects and have had no problems. But one project, the largest and most complex continues to have 14 rendering errors and always the displayed err message "An internal error occurred. Editing functionality may be limited."  The strange thing is going in and out of viewing  Main.storyboard several times gets rid of the errors eventually.  Unfortunately, the errors always come back when I open the project.  And sometimes they go away, then come back randomly in the same session.

So the answer to "whats the simplest way to copy a project folder to new computer is just that - Copy the project folder!  But thats the wrong question for this problem.

Comment: No the best way is to use source control, which you should already be using, and not just for distribution purposes.

Comment: I’m sure you’re right about being the best, but certainly not the simplest which is what frustration often drives for. I’m a little surprised at the negativity this question has generated without any real help with the actual problem.

Comment: I don't think I'm being negative.  It is the simplest method once you've learned how to use the tools freely available to you.  I can't remember the last time I copied a project anywhere; it all gets synced to a server with a few simple commands.